# Ajax Collapsible panel extender flickering

Tags: css, ajax, collapsiblepanelextender

I'm using two collapsible panel extenders in my web page, while executing some function which is in update panel first collapsible panel is flashing i.e opening and closing as a flash, I tried to set the height of the collapsible panel to zero but not get succeded, can anyone suggest how to overcome this collapsible panel flickering issue.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with your code?

Comment: Thank you for your response, I can't do due to policies..

Comment: I'm executing Javascript function in server side button click event(this button is in Ajax update panel) with scriptManager, this first collapsible panel extender is opening a second and immediately closing as a flicker, i have tried by commenting the calling of javascript function in Button click event, then flickering is not happening but calling of javascript function is needed to meet the requirement. Can anyone suggest...